# How to display data inside a single form from database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, input

I am trying to display data from database inside single input form.
Let's say I have 3 rows with column called `name`.

```
<input value"<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
```

This is how I am getting the rows:

```php
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>  <input value="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>">  <?php } mysqli_close($con); ?>
```

So how do i display the data in one input form instead of three?
like in the picture attached.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are doing this:

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>  <input value="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>">  <?php } mysqli_close($con); ?>
```

You are essentially creating as many input lines as the loop iterates.
Instead you should do this:

```
<?php $userNames = []; while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {$userNames[] = $row['username'];} mysqli_close($con); ?>
```

And now we have a nice $userNames array that we shall implode and put in our input line:

```
<?php $userNames = implode(",",$userNames);?>
<input value="<?php echo $userNames; ?>">
```

Don't use while loops to create the form itself... use them to setup the data....

When creating tables or select form data and such using loops is a good idea if you understand what is going on inside the loop :)

There are many more ways to go on this...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, this is what you are trying to get.

```
<?php
$val = '';
while($row = $dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  
{
    $val .= ((!empty($val) ? ', ': '' ) . $row['name'];
}
?>
<input value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($val, ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have separate rows stored in array variable `$row`.

You can add these fields concatenated in the input like this:

```php
<?php $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); ?>
<?php mysqli_close($con); ?>
<input value="<?php echo implode(", ", $row); ?>">
```

Comment: *3 rows with column called `name`*, your example is 3 columns 1 row

Comment: Thx for feedback. Updatet my answer.

Comment: Okay i understand that one, what if i have name1, name2, name3 as seperate rows and i wanna display then in one input.

Comment: @user6473261 See my updatet answer. That should work.

Comment: @GerarddeVisser Yes its working for columns but i need help with 3 rows and 1 column, please assists

Comment: You have code to get the three different rows from the db? Then you can add this to the input as explained in answer. Like: `<input value="<?php echo $row1 . ', ' . $row2 . ', ' . $row3; ?>">`

Comment: @GerarddeVisser Yes this is how am getting the rows. ```<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>

<input value="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>">

<?php
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>```

Comment: @user6473261 I've updatet my answer. Can you check this?